# What does the OID value in my CSR mean?

Tags: code-signing, timestamp

I am applying for a new code signing certificate and I specified to the CA I need a certificate that will be time stamped such that any assembly signed during the valid date range will still execute even beyond that date range.  They sent a template for creating the CSR containing  OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3

Does this value mean the certificate will be time stamped as I requested?  A 10 year old stackexchange post indicates the RFC 3161 correct OID for time stamping is 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8
[What Enhanced Key Usages are required for PKI infrastructure tasks? (OIDs for OSPF and CRL signing, etc)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26648/what-enhanced-key-usages-are-required-for-pki-infrastructure-tasks-oids-for-os)

Comment: *"a certificate that will be time stamped"* - What do you mean? A certificate will have two dates: A date *before* which it is not yet valid and a date *after* which it is not valid any more. And of course the CA will set a stamp, when this certificate was issued.

Comment: Or are you going to implement a Time Stamp Authority?

Comment: Yes. that is exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

A search for [oid 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3](https://www.google.com/search?q=oid+1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) returns for me as the first hit [the entry in the OID reference database](https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) which says:

> Description by oid_info 
> **Indicates that a certificate can be used for
> code signing**

> Does this value mean the certificate will be time stamped as I requested?

No. This is not how timestamping in the context of code signatures work. It is not the code signing certificate which gets timestamped but the code itself is timestamped. And this timestamping of the code is not done with the code signing certificate but by some external timestamp service. And the signature created by this timestamp service gets included into the code signature as a countersignature. See [Verifying Windows binaries, without Windows](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2020/05/27/verifying-windows-binaries-without-windows/) for deeper technical details how this is then stored.

This means that the code signing certificate itself will not have any OID related to timestamping, only OID related to code signing.

Comment: I read that as well, but it does not indicate if the certificate will be time stamped. Not all code signing certs are time stamped.

Comment: @user204427: I've updated the answer to explain how timestamping in code signing works and why you don't have a OID related to timestamping in your code signing certificate.

Comment: Steffen is correct. It is done with a signing tool as [explained further by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/time-stamping-authenticode-signatures): > "Signing tools from Microsoft allow developers to affix time stamps
> at the same time as they affix Authenticode signatures. Time stamping
> allows Authenticode signatures to be verifiable even after the
> certificates used for signature have expired."